# I can't find the drivers for windows 10 on my model c855d

Tags: windows-10

I can't find the drivers for windows 10 on my model c855d, what should I do, I can't use my function keys: volume and others.

thanks for the help

Comment: You might try the Win 8.1 driver and see if the handles it ok.  https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3478326&osId=38

Comment: Toshiba doesn't support windows 10 for your computer. Some functions might work using latest drivers, but it's not possible to predict without actually trying it.